# firebase web app quickstart-js functions sample project gives error when calling functions

Tags: firebase

I'm new to firebase.

I'm trying to get the web "quickstart-js -> functions" sample web app working.

I copied the sample into my project, got it to compile, and deployed it.

The web UI is fine.  Running the functions is failing.

When I put in the two numbers and press the Add Numbers button, I always get:

```
Error Code: functions/internal
Error Message:internal
Error Details:undefined
```

I looked at the server logs, and I didn't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Was using Firefox and having this problem.  On a whim tried it in Chrome.  Works fine in Chrome.

Ended up removing the  tags around the little forms.  Seems like if you put a button in a form and click it, Firefox thinks you're submitting the form, so no firebase goodness happens.  Go figure.  Faith in firebase restored.